# Update import/require paths when a file is moved or renamed - not working

Tags: javascript, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have a javascript project and find that new vs code feature "[Update import paths when a file is moved or renamed](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_update-import-paths-when-a-file-is-moved-or-renamed)" does not work for me. I have tried both: **import** and **require** statements. And for both options vs code does nothing about changing path after move or rename.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Visual Studio Code version 1.25.0
VS Code user settings:

```
{  
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always"  
}
```

Have an empty `jsconfig.json` file in the project folder.

Comment: You need to use Typescript for that functionality. To be precise, Typescript 2.9 or newer. Are you using Typescript?

Comment: No, I am using JavaScript. But in the documentation of VS Code update is mentioned: "VS Code can now automatically update import paths when a **JavaScript** or TypeScript file is moved or renamed". And in settings, there are two separate options:  `javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled` and `typescript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. In my configuration file says it needs TypeScript, but you are right, I have checked the documentation. I don't know what could be happening, I have it in "prompt" and works correctly, have you tried with "prompt"?

Comment: I have tried with both "always" and "prompt" and unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: Same issues for me on 1.30.2

Comment: You should try updating to a more recent version of visual studio code. It’s current version is around 1.40.

Answer (score 7):

So, you need to have a `jsconfig.json` file in the root path, to make sure all paths work.

Comment: It works for me now! I had to add `"allowJs": true` to my `tsconfig.json`. You put me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, but once you move something around you still have to wait for the little loading spinner at the bottom bar to finish before it updates your files properly.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to recreate your problem with the current version of Visual Studio Code (1.44) but I did not stumble on any problems: In File/Preferences/Settings I set the prompt-option for updating imports [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Y7Q.png):

[image]

Then I created an "app"-folder with the following files [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy017.png):

[image]

app/appLogic.js

```
import GLOBAL_VARS from './GLOBAL_VARS/GLOBAL_VARS.js'
console.debug(GLOBAL_VARS.laugh())
```

app/package.json

```
{
"type":"module"
}
```

app/GLOBAL_VARS/GLOBAL_VARS.js

```
var LAUGH = "haha"
export default {
    laugh(){
        return LAUGH
    }
}
```

I then moved the JS file "GLOBAL_VARS.js" to a different folder and VS Code suggested automatic imports update with a prompt, just as set in the preferences before [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVMMm.png):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you opened the right folder in VScode - eg if your project structure is like below -

```
project
/node_modules
/src
 --A.js
 --B.js
/build
/config
package.json
jsconfig.json
```

You open folder project in VScode and not 'src' folder.For some reasons VSCode is unable to detect import changes if you do not open the complete project folder in explorer.

[image: Try open complete project in explorer]